# How to generate url-key for product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, url-key

I am creating products programmatically in my magento store by a PHP script. Everything is going correct but url-key not showing correct.

**For example** : 
I have a product `Test` already in store which has url-key `test` and frontend url is `test.html`. 
Now when I create a new product with name `Test` then it is showing url-key `test` in admin panel but in frontend url is `test-123.html` showing.

I want to set url-key as `test-123` in admin panel also.

How to do that at the time of product creation?

Comment: I think in your url_rewrite table some other url has `test` so that's why it create another entry with `test-123` in that case if you dont need old url then just delete or truncate `url_rewrite` table and do reindexing this way new url key would be generated

Answer (score 2):

For Update Url Key :

```
$product=Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->load(34441);
$old_url_key = $product->getUrlKey();
$product->setUrlKey($manufacturer . ’-’ . $old_url_key);
$product->save();
```

Comment: I know very well how to get and save product attribute or filed but my question is at the time of product creation is it possible to set `url_key` so that no rewrite generated in magento store?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$fp = fopen('getUrl.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku","url_key");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $url = $product->getUrlKey();
    fputcsv($fp, array($sku,$url), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
 ?>
```